# ¿Cómo aplicar la función de buscar en una estructura en lenguaje c?

Tags: c

Tengo este código de estructura y lo que quiero hacer es dar la función de búsqueda, o sea que se le pida un valor al usuario para buscar y que el código devuelva si el valor se encuentra o no, posteriormente también que incluya que se pueda eliminar el valor encontrado, pero no logro que funcione. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Básicamente algo así quiero que se muestre:

```
Da valor a buscar: 5

valor encontrado

Da valor a buscar: 7

valor no encontrado
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista

{
    
int clave;

struct lista *sig;
};


int main()
{
    struct lista *inicio;
    struct lista *nuevo;
    struct lista *aux;
    int i;
    int valor;
    inicio=NULL;
    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        nuevo=(struct lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
        printf("da un valor: ");
        scanf("%d", &nuevo->clave);
        nuevo->sig=inicio;
        inicio=nuevo;
        
    }
    
    aux=inicio;
    
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d->", aux->clave);
        aux=aux->sig;
        
    }
    
    
  
   
     printf("\nDa el valor a buscar: ");
    scanf("%d", &valor);

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
        if(valor==aux)
            printf("Valor encontrado!\n");
        else
            printf("Valor NO encontrado!\n");
   }
 
    
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Te falta setear `inicio->sig = NULL` y pasar al siguiente elemento en el loop de búsqueda con `aux=aux->sig`. Por cierto, no es buena idea usar for con un entero para recorrer la lista en este caso, en lugar de `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` considera `for(struct lista *i = inicio; i != NULL; i = i->sig)`